# SoftDelete works on typeorm with dropSchema true?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm implementing a test database which uses typeorm with dropSchema activated.
And I noticed... my delete routes which calls a softdelete method just remove the row(until the dabase drops). But it works fine at normal database (dropSchema off).

Answer (score 0):

From [TypeOrm Connection Options](http://%22https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options%22) :

> `dropSchema` - Drops the schema each time connection is being
> established. Be careful with this option and don't use this in
> production - otherwise **you'll lose all production data**. This option is
> useful during debug and development.

So when you run with `dropSchema: true` all the data gets deleted including the soft-deleted rows.

Comment: I think i don't have formulate my question right. I know that when connection close drop schema clear all data. My question is because until the schema be dropped when i call soft delete it clear the row instead of updating that deletedate. In non dropSchema enviroment the soft delete works fine